# jQuery fadeOut / fadeIn scroll issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery fadeOut & fadeIn to dynamically change the content on a page, inside a div. All browsers work great, except Chrome for Mac. In Chrome for Mac, on the first page, if you scroll down, fadeOut and then fadeIn the newly faded in content is "off the screen" - in other words, missing. If you don't scroll down on the first page, and go to the second page, the content is displayed just fine.

I have created a simple demo on my site. Again, this works in every browser but Chrome for Mac. Please help! Chrome for Windows works fine.

Demo: http://dev.corecoding.com/problem.php

On the Mac, I am seeing a user agent with AppleWebKit/534.57.2, and in Windows it uses AppleWebKit/536.5. The interesting bit is that it works fine in Safari for Mac, which uses the same (older) WebKit.

Is there a way to make this work with another jQuery / javascript commands? Or should I just forget about it and wait for Chrome's WebKit to be updated?

Comment: Seemed to work just fine for me, scrolled down and hit next question only to see the text displayed fine. Chrome 19.0.1084.56

Comment: I am running chrome and this looks fine.

Comment: I have just confirmed that the issue exists in Mac Chrome only. Windows works fine. Sigh.

Comment: There are layout issues in the recent builds of Mac...

Comment: Thanks @PraveenKumar, this is what I was thinking too as it works in all other environments.

Comment: @fordracerguy Yeah, even I have got annoyed because of this. I don't think there's any fix and no one has ever complained about this. One more thing is, there is an issue with Mac Firefox too!!! I guess the problem is because of Mac OS!!! :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Mac, but you can fix the problem by calling:

```
$("#content").scrollTop(0)
```

After replacing the contents of the div.

Comment: I have tried this, and it does not work. Code has been updated for proof.

Comment: mmm, weird... then I can't help you since I can't test it. What does $("#content").scrollTop() return?
If you eliminate the fade and do a regular show, does it work?

Comment: show still has issues, but if I simply do no animation at all, emptying div and appending content, it works fine. I think I will chalk this up as a rendering issue as @Praveen Kumar has said above